# Javascript trigger event based on data-selector attribute

Tags: javascript

I have a nav bar with following items

```
<li>
  <a href="#" data-parent="1" data-selector="nav a" class="">Blog</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#" data-parent="1" data-selector="nav a" class="">Home</a>
</li>
```

When i hover the item the class of the corresponding link will be `hover` like if i hover on `Blog` the list will be

```
<li>
  <a href="#" data-parent="1" data-selector="nav a" class="hover">Blog</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#" data-parent="1" data-selector="nav a" class="">Home</a>
</li>
```

When i click on it the class will change from `hover` to `open`.

I want to listen the event of click to know that `<a>` with `data-selector="nav a"` is clicked. Whether it is Blog or Home whatever it be i want to call a single function. If `<a>` with `data-selector="nav a"` is clicked and class is `open` i want to do some other task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`document.querySelectorAll('li a')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all your links, then with `forEach`, add the proper event listener to your links with [`link.addEventListener(event, handler)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

You can use the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to add and remove the `hover` class using the `classList` property of your links.

And you can use the `click` event to handle the clicks, then with [`link.getAttribute('data-selector')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) you can query your `data-selector` attribute and do something with it:

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('li a');

links.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('mouseenter', event => {
    if (!link.classList.contains('open')) {
      link.classList.add('hover');
    }
  });
  link.addEventListener('mouseleave', event => {
    link.classList.remove('hover');
  });
  link.addEventListener('click', event => {
    link.classList.remove('hover');
    link.classList.toggle('open');
    const dataSelector = link.getAttribute('data-selector');
    if (dataSelector === 'nav a') {
      console.log('this is a [nav a] link');
    } else {
      console.log('this is NOT a [nav a] link');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hover {
  color: blue;
}
.open {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="#" data-parent="1" data-selector="nav a">Blog</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#" data-parent="1" data-selector="not nav a">Home</a>
</li>
```

Comment: When i use `const links = document.querySelectorAll('li a');` in my console it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks @jo_va. This works for the functionality but there are some other issues with my entire functionality.